# how to integrate ofbiz with sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ofbiz

i need help.How to integrate the ofbiz with sharepoint 2010

Comment: this is not really a valid question for SO, I would suggest using google to get to a point where you need help with a more specific request.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct integration possible with Apache OFBiz and SharePoint. OFBiz is based on JAVA platform that you can run on TomCat or JBOSS, while SharePoint runs on IIS and .NET. You can do some primitive integration by using Portlets and WSRP webparts in SharePoint. I am not sure if OFBiz supports portlets/JSR168 but it is possible to setup WSRP Consumer and Provider and view them using WSRP WebParts. There are also some third party WSRP toolkits

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider replacing Sharepoint with OFBiz, what we are doing for one of our customers at the moment. You will save a lot of license fees and will avoid the amount of clutter (unorganized data) which people will create in your system.